# Simpler way to express the affine variety V(f, g, h) in terms of union and intersection of varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

Is it correct that we can write the affine variety $V(xy, xz, yz)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ as $$[V(x) \cup V(y, z)] \cup [V(x, y) \cup V(z)]?$$ Is there another way to write this in order to better imagine the variety?

Comment: Note that your answer is not likely to be correct as written because $V(x)$ is an entire plane which makes $xy,xz$ vanish, but cannot force $yz$ to vanish.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the following

$$\begin{align}
&V(f,g,h)=V(f)\cap V(g)\cap V(h)\\
&V(f\cdot g)=V(f)\cup V(g)
\end{align}$$

One has

$$
\begin{align}
V(xy,xz,yz)&=V(xy)\cap V(xz)\cap V(yz)\\
&=\left(V(x)\cup V(y)\right)\cap\left(V(x)\cup V(z)\right)\cap\left(V(y)\cup V(z)\right)
\end{align}
$$

Can you take it from here using

$$A\cup(B\cap C)=(A\cup B)\cap(A\cup C)$$